# How to fix my multiplication in my Calculator BASH script

Tags: bash

I've been making a calculator in BASH for a school project. However, the multiplication code isn't working.

```
    #!/bin/bash
        input="yes"
       while [[ $input = "yes" ]]
       do

  #type in the number that correponds to math operation you want to do

     PS3="Press 1 for Addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication
    4 for division: "
    select math in Addition Subtraction Multiplication Division
    do
    case "$math" in
    Addition)
    #enter numbers
      echo "Enter first no:"
        read num1
        echo "Enter second no:"
        read num2
        result=`expr $num1 + $num2`
        echo Answer: $result
        break
    ;;
   #enter numbers
    Subtraction)
        echo "Enter first no:"
        read num1
        echo "Enter second no:"
        read num2
        result=`expr $num1 - $num2`
        echo Answer: $result
        break
    ;;
    #thing that needs to be fixed
    Multiplication)
        echo "Enter first no:"
        read num1
        echo "Enter second no:"
        read num2
        $result= expr $num1 * $num2
        echo Answer: $result
        break
    ;;
    #enter numbers
    Division)
        echo "Enter first no:"
        read num1
        echo "Enter second no:"
        read num2
        result=$(expr "scale=2; $num1/$num2" | bc)
        echo Answer = $result
        break
        ;;
        *)
        break
        ;; 
         esac
         done
         done
```

Comment: You should use shellcheck.net to review your code.

Comment: You should write what is the expected output and what is the error to make easier for people to help you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

The shell expands `*` to all the files in the current directory (`PWD`), a process called "[globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)", unless escaped:

```
$ expr 2 * 2
expr: syntax error
$ expr 2 \* 2
4
```

Good luck with the assignment! Once you're done I would recommend submitting your code for [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `expr` just use the [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html)

```
result=$((num1 * num2))
```